# Nginx Proxy for SSH Strapi Backend not responding

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, strapi

I am currently developing a web study for my research using Strapi for my backend on a virtual machine. Although all have been running smoothly, now that I am going for full deployment, I ran into a minor issue that I cannot seem to get my head around.

The frontend is already online, running on Nginx (v.1.18.0) For security and best practice, I generated an SSL certificate for my domain and rerouted all HTTP requests to HTTPS which worked fine.

However, Strapi is still running on localhost:1337 without HTTPS, understandably causing for browsers to refuse to connect. In response to that, I followed Strapi's documentation to set up a proxy ([Nginx Proxying](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/optional-software/nginx-proxy.html#nginx-virtual-host)) but when trying to curl the proxy, I get an unresolved host error.

I am quite new to Ngnix and Strapi. When I test `nginx -t`, it responses successfully. Yet, the proxy is not working.

Below, my files:

My ./config/env/production/server.js is still quite basic and looks as follows:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    host: env('HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
    url: 'https://api.my-domain.com',
    app: {
        keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
    },
});
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

```
# Strapi server
upstream strapi {
    server 127.0.0.1:1337;
}
```

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/strapi.conf (within `location`, i added the `return 200 'OK'` for testing..)

```
server {
    # Listen HTTP
    listen 80;
    server_name api.my-domain.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    # Listen HTTPS
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.my-domain.com;

    # SSL config
    ssl_certificate path/to/certificate/fullchain.pem
    ssl_certificate_key path/to/certificate/privkey.pem


    # Proxy Config
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://strapi/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        return 200 "OK";
    }
}
```

I changed the default domain to a custom file - gonna keep calling it default here thoguh:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
       

        root /var/www/my-domain/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name my-domain.com www.my-domain.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl ;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ;
        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        root /var/www/my-domain.com/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name my-domain.com; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

       ssl_certificate path/to/certificate/fullchain.pem
       ssl_certificate_key path/to/certificate/privkey.pem
}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

- **Strapi Version**: 4.4.3
- **Operating System**:  Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
- **Database**: MySQL
- **Node Version**: v18.10.0
- **NPM Version**: 8.19.2
- **Yarn Version**: 1.22.19

---

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, following multiple guides can quickly turn any Nginx config into a mess. I went through it all and cleaned my files. The resulting one works like a charm:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/certificate/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/certificate/privkey.pem;

        root /var/www/my-domain/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name my-domain.com www.my-domain.de;

        # Proxy Config
        location /strapi/ {
        rewrite ^/strapi/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://strapi/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        return 200 "OK";
    }
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```